# Flutter FCM token as a global variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have already generated a Firebase token inside my app and I need to use it elsewhere in my code but all of the tutorials I have seen don't use it outside the

```
FirebaseMessaging.getToken.then((token){
print(token);
})
```

How can I use this variable elsewhere in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can save it in sharedPrefs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options,
First is to save it in SharedPrefs, if you want to store it and use it even after relaunching the application.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getToken.then((token){
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("Token",token);
})
```

and retrieve it anywhere in the app with

```
prefs.getString("Token");
```

You can also create a static variable in any class and use it but it will be available for only single launch.

```
class TokenClass {
  static String token = "temp";
}
```

set and get it using `TokenClass.token`

Answer (score 0):

You can save in `sharedPrefs` or you can define global variable in your app.

*globals.dart*:

```
library myGlobals.globals;

String token;
```

and set global variables:

```
import 'package:PROJECT_NAME/globals.dart' as globals;
FirebaseMessaging.getToken.then((token){
  globals.token = token;
})
```

and use:

```
import 'package:PROJECT_NAME/globals.dart' as globals;
print(globals.token)
```

Comment: I tried this and globals.token doesn't print because it's null.

Comment: Never mind I made a mistake when trying your method